# Reviving a bricked MediaPad M2 10.0

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, huawei, emui

I own a `Huawei MediaPad M2 10.0` (M2-01AL). It was rooted since long.

I wanted to try to install Magisk, so I did it from Magisk Manager. I don't exactly remember *what I exactly did*, but eventually I screw up the tablet entirely that it entered a boot loop at the Huawei logo.

#### I just want to reflash it from stock, or something that boots

I have tried several fastboot flashing, but **eventually** got my hands, thanks to XDA, on what look like official stock firmwares by Huawei. File names:

- Huawei_MediaPad%20M2%2010.0%20LTE_Firmware_M2-A01L_V100R001C178B003CUSTC178D001_Android%205.1.1_EMUI%203.1_Finland.rar
- HUAWEI_MediaPad_M2_10.0_Firmware_M2-A01L_Android%205.1.1_EMUI%203.1_V100R001C209B005CUSTC458D001_Malaysia_Channel-Others.rar
- [HUAWEI_MediaPad+M2+10.0_M2-A01L_Firmware_Android+5.1.1_EMUI+3.1_V100R001C100B010CUSTC100D001_Germany_Spain_Belgium.rar](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=745425885120742870)

These archives contain the magic `update.app` to be put into SD card and then boot the tablet with all keys pressed.

The firmware flashes the entire contents of the archive into the ROM. However such a flashing stops at around 90% with a generic failure message and request to reboot.

The tablet won't boot.

This is entirely a software problem with the device.

Also tried extracting the .img from the .app with Huawei Extractor and flashing `system` via fastboot, no result. Phone is still unlocked and FRP is unlocked, as the bootloader reports. I can flash `recovery` successfully, but I haven't yet found an English TWRP, only luck Chinese and Russian.

Question is: how do I restore this tablet to at least a bootable state? I would like to try this alone before going to a repair shop in my city, there are plenties of it.

### Updates

I have successfully installed TWRP in a language I understand. I can see that the `system` partition is damaged because TWRP, on reboot, says that no OS is installed. This is a first step. I also reflashed stock `boot` just to make sure, because I found that in order to uninstall Magisk one has to flash the backup Magisk makes. Unfortunately I had no time to fetch that backup, I was too lazy. Anyway I extracted `system` from the `update.app` and flashed it via fastboot. No result, the tablet is still in boot loop

Comment: Of course I will edit my question to provide any possible clarification upon comments

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I have sold the device as scrap and answer is no longer required

Comment: three years later, just for the protocol (you probably meanwhile figured out) the reason for stock ROM not booting along with modified recovery was most likely [dm-verity](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity)

Comment: Doesn't stock ROM provide stock recovery as well?

Comment: yes. but you only flashed extracted system and boot